# Merge sort in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to figure out what's wrong with this merge sort implementation.  I've narrowed it down to when I concatenate what remains of the left and right arrays.  In the third loop of the recursion, something goes wrong.

```
-(NSArray *)mergeSort:(NSArray *)unsortedArray
{
  //unsortedArray is 4,2,6,5,3,9
  if ([unsortedArray count] < 2)
 {
    return unsortedArray;
 }
   int middle = ([unsortedArray count]/2);
   NSRange left = NSMakeRange(0, middle);
   NSRange right = NSMakeRange(middle, ([unsortedArray count] - middle));
   NSArray *rightArr = [unsortedArray subarrayWithRange:right];
   NSArray *leftArr = [unsortedArray subarrayWithRange:left];
   return [self merge:[self mergeSort:leftArr] andRight:[self mergeSort:rightArr]];
}

-(NSArray *)merge:(NSArray *)leftArr andRight:(NSArray *)rightArr
{
  NSMutableArray *result = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
  int right = 0;
  int left = 0;

  while (left < [leftArr count] && right < [rightArr count])
  {
    if ([leftArr objectAtIndex:left] < [rightArr objectAtIndex:right])
    {
        [result addObject:[leftArr objectAtIndex:left++]];
    }
    else
    {
        [result addObject:[rightArr objectAtIndex:right++]];
    }
 }
  NSRange leftRange = NSMakeRange(left, ([leftArr count] - left));
  NSRange rightRange = NSMakeRange(right, ([rightArr count] - right));
  NSArray *newRight = [rightArr subarrayWithRange:rightRange];
  NSArray *newLeft = [leftArr subarrayWithRange:leftRange];
  newLeft = [result arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:newLeft];
  return [newLeft arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:newRight];
}
```

BTW, this is not homework.  I'm a self-taught programmer trying to learn a little CS.  Thanks everyone.

Comment: What do you mean "something goes wrong"? What is the wrong behavior?

Comment: The output is not in ascending order for the given array.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't use the `<` (less than) operator to compare two objects. Use the `compare:` method:

Replace:

```
if ([leftArr objectAtIndex:left] < [rightArr objectAtIndex:right])
```

with:

```
NSComparsionResult result = [leftArr[left] compare:rightArr[right]];
if (result == NSOrderedAscending) // equivalent to <
```

As "rob" points out, it would be even better to use:

```
if (result != NSOrderedDescending) // equivalent to <=
```

BTW - using `<` with two objects is causing problems because you are comparing the pointer addresses of the two objects. So you end up sorting the objects based on their location in memory and not by their value.

And of course using the `compare:` method assumes the objects in the array actually implement the `compare:` method. This is true for things like `NSString`, `NSNumber`, and `NSDate`. If these are custom objects you need to implement an equivalent method.

Comment: Check `result != NSOrderedDescending` instead to make it a stable sort.

Answer (score 1):

The issue certainly is the comparison:

Replacing:

```
if ([leftArr objectAtIndex:left] < [rightArr objectAtIndex:right])
```

for:

```
 if ([[leftArr objectAtIndex:left] intValue] < [[rightArr objectAtIndex:right] intValue])
```

will also work.